# New to python need to send data over already connected TCP port without waiting for request from client

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

7 socket listener setup. It works great and keeps the connection open, non blocking, all that. From time to time a file will show up that I need to hand back to the client. That works to, but it only send the data in the file if the client sends a character first. I need to have it send the data when the file shows up and not wait. I am coming from php and know what I am doing there. Python is new to me so there are some nuances I don't understand about this code.

```
        while True:                
            try:
                #I want this bit here to fire without waiting for the client to send anything
                #right now it works except the client has to send a character first
                #check for stuff to send back
                for fname in os.listdir('data/%s/in' % dirname):  
                    print(fname)
                    f = open('data/%s/in/%s' % (dirname, fname), "r")
                    client.send(f.readline()) 
                        
                data = client.recv(size)
                if data:
                    
                    bucket=bucket+data
                      
                else:
                    raise error('Client disconnected')
                    
                
            except Exception as e:
                client.close()
                print(e)
                return False
```

Comment: You could read from the socket on the different thread than you're writing from.

Comment: would that require 2 connections to the client? I could have multiple clients and each one is its own conversation...

Comment: No, you do not need multiple connections.  A single socket connection can be used in multiple threads, one thread reading, one thread writing, for instance.